# Rails route for non-resource for csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, routes, custom-routes, respond-to

I have a method called "revisions", and I want to be able use the same logic but output to csv.  I think I'd like to use the FasterCSV gem.  What I need is to what to add to my routes in order to get a route for both the html and the csv outputs.  I'd like my urls to be something like this:

```
invoices/51/revisions
invoices/51/revisions.csv
```

Thoughts?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails makes this very easy. You don't need to change your routes at all to accommodate CSV format, since rails recognizes the csv MIME-type.

First, set up a route in routes.rb:

```
map.invoice_revisions 'invoices/:id/revisions.:format', 
                      :controller=>:invoices, 
                      :action=>:revisions
```

In your controller, do something like this:

```
def revisions
  # ... set @revisions with something like
  @revisions = Invoice.find(params[:id]).revisions

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # will render the revisions html template
    format.csv { render :csv => revisions_csv } # see sample method below
    end
  end
end

private
  def revisions_csv # convert @revisions to csv: customize to your needs
    FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << @revisions.first.attributes.keys  # set the headers
      @revisions.each do |revision|            # set the data
        csv << revision.attributes.values
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's a tutorial with more detailed info on formatting the csv files using csvbuilder:

http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2009/07/csv-views-with-fastercsv-and-csvbuilder.html

Comment: Even with the respond_to in there, I am getting:  Couldn't find WorkOrder with ID=revisions

Comment: Look again at the updated answer. I added some info on setting up your routes. I assumed you already had a route set up for the html version of the view.

Comment: oops... here's the route:         map.invoice_revision 'invoices/:id/revisions', :controller=>:invoices, :action=>:revisions           ...     along with this one before it:             map.resources :invoices, :collection=>{:browse=>:get}, :member=>{:select=>:post}

Comment: OK, the routes I had in my answer were not quite right. What you are missing in your routes is `.:format` at the end to capture the `.csv` . I also updated my answer to look for `:id` instead of `:invoice_id` . Please see the updated answer and check if it works.

Comment: (Sorry, I would have checked/responded sooner if stackoverflow were to email me when I got these responses!)  ...  now on to figuring out the csv part.    THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad you got it working. The CSV part should be relatively easy.

Comment: Turns out it was.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb:

```
resources :photos do
  get 'preview', :on => :member
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

And in your controller, handle the format with a respond_to.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting, even with this route:   Couldn't find Invoice with ID=revisions

Comment: What is the exact url you are trying to visit?